# Button onclick event in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to build a cell within a table . The cell is going to be a button which should open the hyperlink(An email address) .How do i write the onclick event

Below is the code in VB for the cell that i'm building

```
 newCell = New TableCell
                newCell.ID = "celRptSelect" & rptRow & "F"
                newCell.Style("width") = rowRptSelectHeadF.Style("width")
                newCell.CssClass = "TableButton"
                newCell.Text = "SME"
                newCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "rpt.SmeEmail")
                newCell.Attributes.Add("runat", "server")
                newRow.Cells.Add(newCell)
```

rpt.SmeEmail is the data that i'm getting from database

Thanks in advance

Comment: Still looking for help on this .

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code

```
newCell.Attributes.Add( "onclick", "CellAction( me )" );
```

Add your script

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
Sub CellAction( tdControl )
  MsgBox tdControl.id
End Sub
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how i can use the code provided. can you be more elaborate on how i can use it please

Comment: In code behind - newCell.Attributes.Add("onclick", "CellAction( me )")

Comment: In Page <script type="text/vbscript">
Sub CellAction(rowRptSelectHeadF)
  MsgBox rowRptSelectHeadF.id;
End Sub
</script>